# How much better does one distribution approximate a value than a second distribution?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, anova, generalized-linear-model, t-test, p-value

**I have two samples (see graphic below), and I would like to know with what degree of certainty I can claim that one of them deviates less from the value 1.0 than the other.**

[image]

I am aware of [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/83494/which-groups-of-results-is-the-closest-to-a-central-point) but I find it rather a descriptive statistic solution. I don't really care that much about the absolute deviation value, but rather about the certainty with which this allows me to choose one distribution over the other as a best approximator.

Formulating this as a hypothesis test, $H_0$ would be that the other sample approximates the value just as well or better. The hypothesis situation actually makes the two samples non-equivalent (i.e. one is the new one, and the other the old one), but it would be neat if this test worked even without this *a priory* directionality --- i.e. if the score of one being better than the other would just be the inverse of the inverse comparison.

Given equal sample sizes a first naïve approach would be to just compute the p-values of the comparisons of both samples to 1, and rank order them. This, however does not take into account that the samples might be on the same side of the value and thus not significally different from each other, or on different sides but at similar distances, so that they are significantly different from each other, but their difference from 1 is statistically the same. I believe a sort of ANOVA is needed, but I am unsure what sort. I have tried to fit a GLM (with no intercept, so as to not just get the comparison of samples), which is summarized as:

```
=======================================================================
Model:            MixedLM Dependent Variable: Q("Volume Change Factor")
No. Observations: 136     Method:             REML                     
No. Groups:       68      Scale:              0.0038                   
Min. group size:  2       Likelihood:         160.0737                 
Max. group size:  2       Converged:          Yes                      
Mean group size:  2.0                                                  
------------------------------------------------------------------------
                         Coef.  Std.Err.     z     P>|z|  [0.025  0.975]
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Processing[Generic]      1.036     0.009  117.950  0.000   1.019   1.053
Processing[Legacy]       0.725     0.009   82.514  0.000   0.707   0.742
uID Var                  0.001     0.013                                
=======================================================================
```

Based on this, how much closer is 0.725 to 1 than 1.036? Would the ratio of t-statistics be a good metric (never heard of something like this being used)?

Please find a minimal working example (which creates the summary and graphic presented herein, and contains the example data) [here](http://chymera.eu/debug/stats/least_different.zip).

Comment: You have some undefined terms in your question that we can't define for you:  you need to define how you want to measure "deviation" in order to choose a  "best"

Comment: What would be viable options? I would define deviation as certainty that the distribution is different from the value, and best as least certain.

Comment: Different in what way? A distribution can be different in many possible ways.  How do you express how different two functions are?

Comment: Different as in “which of the two distributions is less likely to have the value 1.0 sampled from it”. It's the same thing as significance testing the distributions against the value. It's just that I cannot compare the resulting p-values to each other.